# Select all the rows for a specific condition and union the ones that match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Given this table in excel

| COLUMN 1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 1 | A |
| Car | 1 | A |
| Apple | 2 | A |
| Apple | 2 | B |
| Apple | 2 | B |
| Tree | 3 | C |
| House | 1 | C |

I would like to filter by column 2 all the distinct elements that are equals to 1.
Result :

| COLUMN 1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 1 | A |
| House | 1 | C |

After this filter, I want to take all the other rows where, after this filter, appear in column 3. In this case A, C are the values, then adding to this filtered list all the rows where  A and C appears.

Result:

| COLUMN 1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 1 | A |
| House | 1 | C |
| Apple | 2 | A |
| Tree | 3 | C |

Is it possible to have this result with one formula? Or I need to do this filtering before and after the union the results?

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365, using UNIQUE and FILTER:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:C7,ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1:C7,UNIQUE(FILTER(C1:C7,B1:B7=1)),0))+(B1:B7=1)))
```

[image]

If one wants to sort it then we can add SORT:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:C7,ISNUMBER(MATCH(C1:C7,UNIQUE(FILTER(C1:C7,B1:B7=1)),0))+(B1:B7=1))),2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer but I'm not able to use FILTER function because I am not into Office 365 context

Comment: Then you are probably going to need to use vba to get what you want.